# What should I do when I see users that all they do is to copy&paste from other sources?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

I'm talking specifically about a user that most of their contributions are editing with copied content.

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3810/threading#t=201607292210095758487
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/46854?draftId=39876
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/4025/attributes#t=201607292207091835203
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/4269/iterators#t=201607292151495540694
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/4540/assemblies#t=20160729221640629005
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/node.js/drafts/39878
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/58688 ([source](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/03/sql-server-computed-column-persisted-and-performance/))
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/4540/assemblies/16381/ensure-assemblies-loaded#t=201607301407055553349 (Updated on 14:10 UTC)
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mongodb-csharp/2610/introduction-to-mongodb-csharp#t=201607301429522588481

So, some proposal were rejected, some reported - But this one just keeps on going! When enough should be enough? Should we let it continue? What is the added value when all you can do is to copy other people's work?

I think that although this question was asked before, it wasn't related to a specific user. I wanted to ask this because the original question @Undo answered *"In need of moderator intervention" flags on Documentation **don't seem to be real flags yet**; they show up as improvement requests and don't enter the moderator queue.*

This not not good enough because this specific user is continuing adding more and more examples like this, and I can't follow his every step AND I also can't flag it for moderator intervention because this feature doesn't work at the moment.

Comment: Sidenote: Aug 9 '15, he lost 1036 rep: _"Voting corrected"_. It looks like he's no stranger to "obtaining" rep by any means necessary.

Comment: Flag, flag, and flag again. (Actually, just do it once.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I know it was asked before, but this question is related to specific user, and Undo wrote _In need of moderator intervention" flags on Documentation don't seem to be real flags yet; they show up as improvement requests and don't enter the moderator queue._ - So I can't really report it to a moderator without asking here and letting someone know about it (It's so annoying that users let themselves copy such great amount of content from external sources)

Comment: [I am in complete agreement](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/117558?m=31941693#31941693) with your annoyance, but Undo said there to raise an "Other" flag on one of the user's Q&A posts reporting the situation.

Comment: @JoshCaswell This made me a little bit less angry. Thanks :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell m not agree with flag things as its not as powerful as it should be. another example is edit spree to get too much rep :(

Comment: As far as I read in chat, @Shog9 has a tool to search the flags (also dismissed ones) for %plagia% … so he'll probably see it … but as it's such many, meta post was probably fine.

Comment: @bwoebi Thanks, i'll use it in my next flags until we'll be able to really flag examples for moderation intervention. I do see a drop it his contribution cations, they dropped from 33 yesterday to 14 (I just flagged more BTW - Because he's something special). Hope a moderator will take active actions with him

Comment: Correction - They didn't dropped at all, I was on the wrong tab

Comment: @CanadianCoder NEVER!

Comment: I think, it needs a moderator's attention.

Comment: Either as a result of incomplete documentation tools or sloppy users, I've also seen documentation examples written by users get copied and pasted over to different topics, denying credit to the original authors. Seems like we really need some solid peer-review tools.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, Stack Overflow moderators don't have much in the way of special powers when it comes to Documentation right now. That makes handling cases of plagiarism difficult. All we can do is provide plagiarism warnings to main SO accounts, which I've done here.

I've also entirely deleted the topics submitted by this person, as all of them were populated by plagiarized content. <strike>The only one I couldn't delete was [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mongodb-csharp/2610/introduction-to-mongodb-csharp#t=201607301429522588481), because I can't seem to find the option for deleting the topic, and the system won't let me delete the plagiarized example and leave the topic without an example.</strike> (That was an introduction topic, which apparently can't be deleted, so I had to roll it back to the original pre-plagiarism revision). If I've missed others, let me know.

Handling plagiarism on Documentation is a pain for moderators right now, so my recommendation is that when you spot it, suggest edits to remove it yourself (deleting examples and topics via edits as necessary) and then flag us on the main site to warn the accounts responsible. That way, it saves moderators the effort of finding and reviewing the source material, since all we'd be able to do is edit like you could. If reviewers reject these edits, let us know.

Comment: @Brand Today I identified more plagiarized content from that user. I have flagged it on the main site and mared the examples. There are other content that was copied, but with changes in the DB table/fields names. I'm pretty sure that there are other plagiarized  examples from him (I stopped checking after 5 copied examples)